# The number of unitary circulant matrices over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, finite-fields, unitary-matrices, circulant-matrices

Suppose $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$, where $q$ is a prime power. The conjugate of elements in $\mathbb{F}$ is defined by $\overline{x}=x^q$. I need to find the number of $n\times n$ unitary circulant matrices over $\mathbb{F}$.

The number of invertible circulant matrices over a finite field can be seen elsewhere, such as [when $n,q$ coprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363372/number-of-invertible-circulant-matrices-over-a-finite-field) and my question [when $n=\operatorname{char} q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646138/number-of-invertible-elements-in-mathbbf-qx-langle-xp-1-rangle-with-p).

Is there any better method to calculate this number other than considering each entry?

---

**Added on 30 May 2020:**

Let $C$ be the subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(q^2)$ of all circulant matrices. Is $C\operatorname{GU}_n(q)$ a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(q^2)$? That is, is $C\operatorname{GU}_n(q)=\operatorname{GU}_n(q)C$? If that is correct then $C\operatorname{GU}_n(q)=\operatorname{GL}_n(q^2)$ and so $|C\cap\operatorname{GU}_n(q)|$ follows. Here we denote by $\operatorname{GU}_n(q)$ the general unitary group over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.

Comment: This question has been already answered in MO. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361871/the-number-of-unitary-circulant-matrices-over-a-finite-field-mathbbf-q2